# When do I use the possessive with "Tiffany & Co"?

Tags: possessives, proper-nouns, saxon-genitive

Is there a grammatical reason for Tiffany & Co being made possessive in *Breakfast at Tiffany's*?

Comment: Because *home of X* and *house of X* take the possessive to make *X’s place*. So one has breakfast *at somebody’s house*, or just plain *at sombody’s*. One does not have breakfast *at *somebody* by itself. This only happens for people, including personified people. Many store names were formally known as *X’s*, and many still are.

Comment: The 'rule' has been relaxed by many businesses and organisations, and their preferences trump English-as-we-knew-it. I'm trying to ascertain whether "lunch at Wetherspoons" ("Serious concerns about the proposed Wetherspoons bar and diner planned for Largs..." /  "A spokesman for Wetherspoon's said ...": internet) is what JD Wetherspoon prefers, but most references do not include the apostrophe. "Breakfast at Tiffany's" is set in stone; my daughter's got the film.

Comment: @tchrist this question is not a duplicate. The answers in the dup do not explain the *grammatical* use of the possessive.

Answer (score 2):

Today the store's full and proper name is *Tiffany & Company*; however, its original name in 1837 was *Tiffany, Young and Ellis* which was shortened to *Tiffany & Company* in 1853.

Colloquially, the store is often referred to as *Tiffany's*, in speech (TIF-uh-nees; or  /ˈtɪfəniz/ ) and in writing.  The use of the apostrophe was often a trait or a type of hallmark for many local businesses and stores in the past, but it also served a purpose, the apostrophe informed its clients that the business, store, shop, bank, etc. they were seeing or entering was founded (and usually owned) by a person.

For example in the UK we have:

- Sainsbury's
- Waterstone's (but since January 2012 the apostrophe is omitted)
- [Lewis's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis%27s) (now defunct)
- Lloyd's of London (often shortened to *Lloyd's*)

The US instead has many more department stores and businesses names with the apostrophe:

- Applebee's
- Bloomingdale's
- Brink's
- CiCi's Pizza
- Dillard's
- Kohl's
- Lowe's
- Macy's
- McDonald's

The use of the apostrophe in *Breakfast at Tiffany's* is orthographically justifiable because one its founders was Charles Lewis Tiffany.

Nevertheless nowadays, possibly dictated by the boom in e-commerce the tendency is to omit the apostrophe "[Of course, URLs don’t allow for apostrophe use, and consumers have become accustomed to the exclusion of such punctuation when seeking a business on the Web.](http://blog.mainstreethost.com/why-are-so-many-brands-forgetting-their-apostrophes#.VAwp3MK1ZWw)"    <sub>Pat DePuy</sub>

The following extract is taken from the English newspaper, The Guardian.

> ### So, Waterstones – no apostrophe? Hey, no catastrophe
>
> [...]
>   The fact is that the way retailers choose to punctuate their name is a
>   mess and certain to remain so. You have the "what's an apostrophe?"
>   camp, of which the market leader is Tesco (colloquially known,
>   ironically, as "Tesco's"); you may have noticed their line of boys
>   toys.
>
> In Tesco's defence, there never was a Mr Tesco, so a possessive
>   apostrophe as in "Tesco's" would be illogical. There were a Marks and
>   a Spencer, but luckily for us they also decided not to cause confusion
>   by using apostrophes, although you do have to remember to employ the
>   ampersand rather than "and" if you want to get *Marks & Spencer*
>   (strictly, "Marks & Sparks") right.
>
> *Boots*, *Morrisons* and now *Waterstones* eschew the apostrophe with less
>   justification, as their shops were founded or developed and owned by, respectively,  Jesse Boot, William Morrison and Tim Waterstone. 
>   [...]
>   Then there are the businesses that actually get it right, headed by *Sainsbury's* (as in Mr Sainsbury's shop) and *McDonald's* (as in Ronald McDonald's Egg McMuffins). The grey area occupied by *Toys R Us's* backward R we will leave for another time.  (cont'd)
>
> <sup>[The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2012/jan/12/waterstones-apostrophe-no-catastrophe)</sup>